# Issue with 1:m (using belongsTo and hasMany). Result doesn't reflect proposed model

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a simple sample app where I am trying to setup a 1 to many relationship between 2 tables. I am using sequelize with mssql (tedious). I have no tables in the database when I start. I connect to the database successfully and then try you create/sync the models to the database.

I have provided my code here to see if anyone has any ideas why I am not able to get the desired result. I have seen some people is *instanceMethods* and *classMethods* and create some object called *associate*, but I see nothing in the documentation about that. What am I missing here? I simply want my **Items** collection to be populated when I query for my Project. Am I setting up the association correctly?

I even considered using *belongsToMany* as follows but it didn't seem to work for me.

```
project.belongsToMany(workitem, {through: 'ProjectWorkItem', as: 'Items', foreignKey: 'workitemId'});
workitem.belongsToMany(project, {through: 'ProjectWorkItem', as: 'Projects', foreignKey: 'projectId'});
```

**index.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('mssql://username:password@localhost:1433/sequelize-test')

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(function (err) {
        const services = require('./models');
        services(sequelize);
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
```

**models\index.js**

```
'use strict';
const WorkItem = require('./workitem-model');
const Project = require('./project-model');


module.exports = function (sequelize) {

  console.log('Pre-configure start');
  const project = Project(sequelize);
  const workitem = WorkItem(sequelize);

  var projectInstance = project.build({
    title: 'very important project',
    description: 'Some description'
  });

  projectInstance
    .save()
    .then(function (savedProject) {
      var itemInstance = workitem.build({
        text: "abc",
        projectId: savedProject.id
      });
      itemInstance
        .save()
        .then(function () {
          project.
          findById(savedProject.id)
            .then(function (dbProject) {

              console.log(dbProject.title);
              // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED - SHOULDN'T THERE BE DATA
              console.log(dbProject.Items);  // <-------------
            });
        });
    });
};
```

**models\workitem.js**

```
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Project = require('./project-model');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
  const workitem = sequelize.define('workitems', {
    text: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  const project = Project(sequelize);
  workitem.belongsTo(project);
  project.hasMany(workitem, {
    as: 'Items'
  });

  workitem.sync();

  return workitem;
};
```

**models\project.js**

```
'use strict';   

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
  const project = sequelize.define('projects', {
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,

  });

  project.sync();

  return project;
};
```

Comment: have you checked the database it contains data?

Comment: Yep, there is data in there. I ran SQL statements in Management Studio to verify that there was data in the tables.

Comment: do console.log(savedProject.id) before project.
          findById(savedProject.id) and check if right id is being passed

Comment: One more thing you are not using promises in correct way

Comment: Saved Project Id: 1
Executing (default): SELECT [id], [title], [description], [createdAt], [updatedAt] FROM [projects] AS [projects] WHERE [projects].[id] = 1;
Db Project Id: 1
undefined

Comment: What am I doing wrong with the Promise? The models\index.js code is throwaway. My main concern is that when I make the call to get the project, the associated workitems are not returned.

Comment: check my answer you need to console.log the saveObject returned from projectInstance
    .save() and check at which level id is there

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
const WorkItem = require('./workitem-model');
const Project = require('./project-model');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {

  console.log('Pre-configure start');
  const project = Project(sequelize);
  const workitem = WorkItem(sequelize);

  var projectInstance = project.build({
    title: 'very important project',
    description: 'Some description'
  });

  return projectInstance
    .save()
    .then(function (savedProject) {
      console.log(savedProject); // check values here. id might be in nested dataValues object e.g. savedProject.dataValues.id;
      var itemInstance = workitem.build({
        text: "abc",
        projectId: savedProject.id
      });
      return itemInstance.save();
    }).then(function (myWorkItem) {
      return project.
      findById(myWorkItem.projectId);
    }).then(function (dbProject) {
      console.log(dbProject.title);
      // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED - SHOULDN'T THERE BE DATA
      console.log(dbProject.Items); // <-------------
      return dbProject;
    });
};
```

Comment: I think my issue is in my model definitions and in the way the relationships are setup. I am just not sure what I am missing there. The code in the models\index.js after the definition was just to prove that my *Items* collection would be populated on a retrieve of the *Project*.

Comment: Also when I use the code provided I get the following error
**Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot set property 'savedProject' of undefined**

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[text]
      ,[createdAt]
      ,[updatedAt]
      ,[projectId]
  FROM [sequelize-test].[dbo].[workitems]
---->
id text createdAt updatedAt projectId
1 abc 2017-02-05 05:20:31.0000000 2017-02-05 05:20:31.0000000 1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a little digging on similar posts on StackOverflow :) Posting the updated code in case any one else needs something similar. The interesting part is that I had to setup a method to do the relationship binding, and then call the associate methods after all of the models had been setup. Additionally, I had to do a sync on sequelize at the end of the process not during, because of all the inter-relations. It makes sense to me now but it was a pain to figure out.

**index.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('mssql://username:password@localhost:1433/sequelize-test')

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(function (err) {
        const services = require('./models');
        services(sequelize);
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
```

**models\workitem-model.js**

```
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
  const workitem = sequelize.define('workitems', {
    text: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        workitem.belongsTo(models.projects);
      }
    },
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  return workitem;
};
```

**models\project-model.js**

```
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
  const project = sequelize.define('projects', {
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        project.hasMany(models.workitems, {
          as: 'Items'
        });
      }
    },
    freezeTableName: true,
  });

  return project;
};
```

**models\index.js**

```
'use strict';
const WorkItem = require('./workitem-model');
const Project = require('./project-model');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {

  console.log('Pre-configure start');
  const project = Project(sequelize);
  const workitem = WorkItem(sequelize);

  // Setup relationships
  const models = sequelize.models;

  Object.keys(models)
    .map(name => models[name])
    .filter(model => model.associate)
    .forEach(model => model.associate(models));

  sequelize.sync();

  var projectInstance = project.build({
    title: 'very important project',
    description: 'Some description'
  });

  return projectInstance
    .save()
    .then(function (savedProject) {

      var itemInstance = workitem.build({
        text: "abc",
        projectId: savedProject.id
      });
      return itemInstance.save();
    }).then(function (myWorkItem) {
      return project.
      findById(myWorkItem.projectId);
    }).then(function (dbProject) {

      dbProject.getItems().then(function (items) {
        console.log(items); // <------- Associated Item data returned
      });

      return dbProject;
    });
};
```